# How to train a network in Keras for varying output size

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, keras

I have basic neural network created with Keras. I train the network successfully with  vectors of data and corresponding output data that is a vector with two elements. It represents a coordinate (x, y). So in goes an array, out comes an array.

Problem is that I am unable to use training data where a single input vector should correspond to many coordinates. Effectively, I desire a vector of coordinates as output, without prior knowledge of the number of coordinates.

Network is created by

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(196608,)))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(2))
```

and model summary shows the output dimensions for each layer

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20)                3932180
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                210
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 22
=================================================================
```

I realize the network structure only allows a length 2 vector as output. Dense layers also do not accept `None` as their size. How do I modify the network so that it can train on and output a vector of vectors (list of coordinates)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An rnn is not what you want for predicting coordinates. Instead, I would recommend using a model that predicts coordinates and associated confidences. So you would have 100 coordinate predictions for every forward pass through your model. Each of those predictions would have another associated prediction that determines if it is correct or not. Only predictions that are above a certain confidence threshold would count. That confidence threshold is what allows the model to choose how many points it wants to use each time (with a maximum number set by the number of outputs which in this example is 100).

r-cnn is a model that does just that. Here is the first keras implementaion I found on github https://github.com/yhenon/keras-frcnn.

Answer (score 4):

A recurrent neural networks (RNNs) would be much more appropriate, this models are typicall called seq2seq, that is, sequence to sequence. Recurrent nets use layers like LSTM and GRU, and can input and output variable length sequences. Just look at things like Machine Translation done with RNNs.

This can be done directly with keras, and there are many examples lying around the internet, for example [this](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/seq2seq) one.

Comment: Do you have any examples using keras only?

Comment: He isn't asking about variable output models in general, the question was about coordinate prediction. This leads me to believe that the dataset is composed of images. sequence to sequence models don't come close to solving his problem.